# What is a TEXT Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>*

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a **TEXT Word™**.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| TEXT Word™ | Not TEXT Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| ME | HIM |
| ON | OFF |
| ALL | NONE |
| BOX | CRATE |
| BUG | INSECT |
| HOT | COLD |
| BEST | WORST |
| BOOK | PAPER |
| HIDE | SHOW |
| MAKE | GIVE |
| EMPTY | FULL |
| HOUSE | CAR |
| ROBOT | HUMAN |
| TREES | FOREST |
| CURSOR | MOUSE |
| FLOWER | BUSH |

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a TEXT Word™ on its own.

These are not the only examples of TEXT Word™ (or non-TEXT Word™), many more exist.

Comment: Are you sure YOU is not a TEXT word? It seems to me like it should be one.

Comment: @Deusovi Indeed. It slipped through my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming there is an error in the question as it currently stands; that *may* not be the case, but it looks very likely that this answer is the intended one.

The answer is that

> each of the TEXT words is a word that appears in [Baba Is You](https://store.steampowered.com/app/736260/Baba_Is_You/), a game about pushing words around to change how objects behave. (And indeed, TEXT itself is also a word that appears there, which can be used to change the properties of the text that makes up the rules.)
>
>  (YOU is also a word in the game, though - it should also be a TEXT word if this guess is correct.)

Comment: Based on this solution, I don't think BOOK and HOUSE should be listed as TEXT Words, and TREES would more accurately be singular.

Comment: @xnor Yes, I believe you're correct. I didn't check through all of them fully, because the title and the reference seemed good enough, and I recognized most of the words. That does seem like an error on OP's part, though.

Comment: @xnor All three you mentioned are available in the level editor (public beta), though they haven't made their way through built-in levels. You can enable betatest in Steam to get the latest version (stable 271, beta 390).